# Does "being in despair" imply more severity than being desperate?

Tags: difference, conversation

Or, do the two words- depair and desperate convey the same feeling

Comment: The words 'despair' and 'desperate', despite looking similar, relate to different emotions.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: They *were* equivalent, obviously. Idiomatically, the meanings have diverged over time, but that might not be easy for a non-Anglophone to establish

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary definitions might not always make this idiomatically established distinction clear...

> 1: If you're *"**in despair**"*, you've ***lost all hope***. You no longer think there's *any* possibility of getting what you want.

> 2: If you're *"**desperate**"*, you ***really need*** something, but generally speaking it's assumed you still hope to get it. But *because* you're desperate, you're prepared to go to any lengths to get it (you still *hope* to get it, even if you're not confident of a successful outcome).